# How to use a LINQ in order to remove Min and Max value in List

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a List such as below.

```
List<int> temp = new List<int> { 3, 5, 6, 8, 2, 1, 6};
```

I'm going to use a LINQ to remove Min and Max value in Above List.

For example, below snippet code is just example, not working.

```
var newValue = from pair in temp
               select pair < temp.Max() && pair > temp.Min()
```

Hopefully, I expect the result like below ;

```
newValue = {3, 5, 6, 2, 6 }
```

I've tried Googling, but couldn't find proper example yet.

Is it workigng when I use a LINQ ? Thanks for your time.

Comment: What happens when you run the code?

Comment: Doesn't work. just null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using `where`.

```
from pair in temp
where pair < temp.Max() && pair > temp.Min()
select pair
```

Your current approach will *select* whether the values are in range, not *filter* them. That's what the `where` clause is for.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:-

```
var query = temp.Where(x => x != temp.Min() && x != temp.Max()).ToList();
```

Working [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3Msv7h).

Comment: Nice! Note that it will remove all the min and max values if there are any duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

if you just need to remove the min and max values you why not just use remove()?  what's the need for the pair?

```
    List<int> temp =new List<int>() { 3, 5, 6, 8, 2, 1, 6 };
    temp.Remove(temp.Max());
    temp.Remove(temp.Min());
```

or something like this if you need to maintain temp and would rather work on a copy

```
temp.Sort();
temp.Skip(1).Take(temp.Count - 2).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

How could you be able to add an array in Generic Collection. Also you have to convert your query result into list. Use the `where` clause as suggested by @Matthew Haugen.

```
List<int> temp = new List<int>();// {3, 5, 6, 8, 2, 1, 6}

temp.Add(3);
temp.Add(5);
temp.Add(6);
temp.Add(8);
temp.Add(2);
temp.Add(1);
temp.Add(6);

List<int> newValue = (from n in temp 
                      where n > temp.Min() & n < temp.Max() 
                      Select n).ToList();
```

Comment: It depends on the use I think, you don't necessarily need to convert it to list. :)