# Get the key and its value and remove it from a Dictionary<string,value> efficently

Tags: c#, dictionary, min

I need to obtain the key and the value of the min value and in the same time to remove this pair of key-value, I have to do in an efficient way, if the dictionary is not the best data structure to do this I can change; this is my dictionary:

`Dictionary<string,int> myDict = new Dictionary<string,int>();`

Comment: What does efficient mean? Time? Memory? Maintainability? How do you remove it at the moment?

Comment: time and complexity, I do not remove it yet

Comment: Finding a min in an unordered sequence is O(N). Removing an element from dictionary by key is O(1). Dictionary is definitely not the best data structure for this particular operation, but changing it to something else will affect other operations like fast lookup/add/remove by key, which is the purpose of the dictionary data structure.

Comment: You can use Linq for this.
See:
[Remove max or min from dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26645096/how-to-use-a-linq-in-order-to-remove-min-and-max-value-in-list)

Comment: What if you have 2 objects with same min value?

Comment: @Aldert it is indifferent which pair is returned if they have the same value and matches the minimum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a DictionaryList what holds a shadow sorted list of values. It is kept in sync with the dictionary.  you can add a key value, remove a key and remove the minimum. This is fast, making O(log n) comparisons, where n is the number of elements in the array. You can now extend this to your liking.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MainClass
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DictionaryList<string, int> dict = new DictionaryList<string, int>();

            dict.Add("assd", 45);
            dict.Add("gh", 78);
            dict.Add("uih", 235);
            dict.Add("sdfg", 345);
            dict.Add("jkl", 456);
            dict.Add("wer", 345);
            dict.Add("dfg", 454);
            dict.Add("we", 490895);
            dict.Add("dfgq", 78);
            dict.Add("jkel", 34);
            dict.Add("wepr", 1);
            dict.Add("zer", 345);
            dict.Add("kt", 345);
            dict.Add("qrk", 345);


            dict.RemoveMinimum();
            dict.Remove("wer");

        }

    }

    public class DictionaryList<Key, Value> : Dictionary<Key, Value> where Value : IComparable where Key : IComparable
    {
        private class MinComparer<Key1, Value1> : IComparer<KeyValuePair<Key1, Value1>> where Value1 : IComparable where Key1:IComparable
        {
            public int Compare(KeyValuePair<Key1, Value1> x, KeyValuePair<Key1, Value1> y)
            {
                int comp = x.Value.CompareTo(y.Value);
                if (comp == 0)
                {
                    return x.Key.CompareTo(y.Key);
                }
                return comp;
            }
        }

        private List<KeyValuePair<Key, Value>> shadowList = new List<KeyValuePair<Key, Value>>();
        private MinComparer<Key, Value> mc = new MinComparer<Key, Value>();

        public new void Add(Key key, Value value)
        {
            base.Add(key, value);

            KeyValuePair<Key, Value> shadow = new KeyValuePair<Key, Value>(key, value);
            int index = shadowList.BinarySearch(shadow, mc);
            if (index < 0) index = ~index;
            shadowList.Insert(index, shadow);
        }

        public void RemoveMinimum()
        {
            if (shadowList.Count > 0)
            {
                this.Remove(shadowList[0].Key);
            }
        }

        public new void Remove(Key key)
        {
            Value shadow = this[key];
            base.Remove(key);

            KeyValuePair<Key, Value> dummy = new KeyValuePair<Key, Value>(key, shadow);

            int index = shadowList.BinarySearch(dummy, mc);

            shadowList.RemoveAt(index);

        }
    }
 }
```